# How to get all the same field matching nested object on JSON

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Below is my JSON Object. In that i need to filter only leaf as true field.

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "title":"ASD Headquarters",
      "items":[
         {
            "id":11,
            "title":"San Jose",
            "items":[
               {
                  "id":13,
                  "title":"Jensen Chapman's Team",
                  "items":[
                     {
                        "id":14,
                        "title":"Jimmy John",
                        "leaf":"true"
                     },
                     {
                        "id":15,
                        "title":"Daniel Mills",
                        "leaf":"true"
                     },
                     {
                        "id":16,
                        "title":"Chris Boden"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":12,
            "title":"Irvine",
            "items":[
               {
                  "id":24,
                  "title":"San Jesus"
               },
               {
                  "id":25,
                  "title":"Fat Albert"
               },
               {
                  "id":26,
                  "title":"Connor McDavid",
                  "leaf":"true"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":30,
            "title":"San Diego",
            "items":[
               {
                  "id":31,
                  "title":"Duran Duran's Team",
                  "items":[
                     {
                        "id":32,
                        "title":"Amberlynn Pinkerton"
                     },
                     {
                        "id":33,
                        "title":"Tony Mejia"
                     },
                     {
                        "id":34,
                        "title":"Richard Partridge",
                        "leaf":"true"
                     },
                     {
                        "id":35,
                        "title":"Elliot Stabler"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":40,
                  "title":"Steely Dan's Team",
                  "items":[
                     {
                        "id":36,
                        "title":"Tony Stark"
                     },
                     {
                        "id":37,
                        "title":"Totally Rad"
                     },
                     {
                        "id":38,
                        "title":"Matt Murdock"
                     },
                     {
                        "id":39,
                        "title":"Stan Lee"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":64,
            "title":"Richard Partridge Stark",
            "leaf":"true"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Output that required is:

```
[
   {
      "id":14,
      "title":"Jimmy John",
      "leaf":"true"
   },
   {
      "id":15,
      "title":"Daniel Mills",
      "leaf":"true"
   },
   {
      "id":26,
      "title":"Connor McDavid",
      "leaf":"true"
   },
   {
      "id":34,
      "title":"Richard Partridge",
      "leaf":"true"
   },
   {
      "id":64,
      "title":"Richard Partridge Stark",
      "leaf":"true"
   }
]
```

Comment: Just create a recursive function, if it is not a `leaf` then pass the `items` attribute to the function.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Below function i used to get the respective data.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.json = [{
      "id":1,
      "title":"ASD Headquarters",
      "items":[
         {
            "id":11,
            "title":"San Jose",
            "items":[
               {
                  "id":13,
                  "title":"Jensen Chapman's Team",
                  "items":[
                     {
                        "id":14,
                        "title":"Jimmy John",
                        "leaf":"true"
                     },
                     {
                        "id":15,
                        "title":"Daniel Mills",
                        "leaf":"true"
                     },
                     {
                        "id":16,
                        "title":"Chris Boden"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":12,
            "title":"Irvine",
            "items":[
               {
                  "id":24,
                  "title":"San Jesus"
               },
               {
                  "id":25,
                  "title":"Fat Albert"
               },
               {
                  "id":26,
                  "title":"Connor McDavid",
                  "leaf":"true"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":30,
            "title":"San Diego",
            "items":[
               {
                  "id":31,
                  "title":"Duran Duran's Team",
                  "items":[
                     {
                        "id":32,
                        "title":"Amberlynn Pinkerton"
                     },
                     {
                        "id":33,
                        "title":"Tony Mejia"
                     },
                     {
                        "id":34,
                        "title":"Richard Partridge",
                        "leaf":"true"
                     },
                     {
                        "id":35,
                        "title":"Elliot Stabler"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":40,
                  "title":"Steely Dan's Team",
                  "items":[
                     {
                        "id":36,
                        "title":"Tony Stark"
                     },
                     {
                        "id":37,
                        "title":"Totally Rad"
                     },
                     {
                        "id":38,
                        "title":"Matt Murdock"
                     },
                     {
                        "id":39,
                        "title":"Stan Lee"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":64,
            "title":"Richard Partridge Stark",
            "leaf":"true"
         }
      ]
   }
];
    $scope.obj = [];
    finddata($scope.json, 'leaf', 'true')
    function finddata(list, key, val) {
        if(!list)
            return;
        list.forEach(item => {
            if(!item)
                return;
            if(item[key] === val){
                $scope.obj.push(item)
                return;
            }else
            finddata(item.items, key, val)
            return;
        })
    }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <pre>{{obj | json}}</pre>
            </div>
```